# How can setup an ubuntu server similar to heroku

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, server

Just purchased a `Virtual Server Cloud` using 1and1. How can I make it that when uploading a node application, (I finally got node installed,) it's as easy as uploading to heroku? How can I set it up like heroku is setup?

And in case you haven't noticed, I'm clueless to server administration. (tutorial links are welcomed.)

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you can make your own server to be like heroku by using CaptainDuckDuck

this github link https://github.com/caprover/caprover and this reference https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-i-cut-my-heroku-cost-by-400-5b9d0220ce13/

Comment: Please post your solution here. Because links are not permanent.